# How do I pause setInterval for 5 min after every 15 times of executing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, if-statement, scripting

I want my `setInterval` function to pause or delay for 5 times
when it's done executing given function 15 times every second.
Here is my script:

```
    var increment = 0;

    var timer = setInterval(makeWork, 1000);

    function makeWork() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[increment].click();
        increment+=1;
    }
```

This functions finds all HTML buttons, and uses dynamic index to click on each.

I tried using setTimeout function but, I think the setInterval keeps moving
even when setTimeout holds the execution.
Here's what I want the code above to do:

1. Click each button 15 times every second
2. Wait for 5 minutes.
3. And continute clicking from 15 to 30
4. Pause again for 5 min, and so on.

Comment: Without seeing any code I'm guessing Instagram is either rate limiting you or thinking you're behaving like a bot. Please show us your code.

Comment: I second @thordarson's request for posting the code. But some rough math based on instagram's rate limits https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/ gives you anywhere from needing an 8 second delay to a 120 second delay between requests.